# R: Strange behavior while saving list() with save() from function output

Tags: r

I am currently facing a strange problem while saving lists and 'sublists' with R. The title may not be explicit but here is what is troubling me :

Given some data (here the data is totaly artificial but the problem isn't the relevance of the model) :

```
set.seed(1)
a0 = rnorm(10000,10,2)
b1 = rnorm(10000,10,2)
b2 = rnorm(10000,10,2)
b3 = rnorm(10000,10,2)
data = data.frame(a0,b1,b2,b3)
```

And a function returning a list of complex objects (let's say `lm()` objects) :

```
test = function(k){
    tt = vector('list',k)
    for(i in 1:k) tt[[i]] = lm(a0~b1+b2+b3,data = data)
    tt
}
```

Our test fonction returns a list of `lm()` objects. Lets look the size of this object :

```
ok = test(2)
object.size(ok)
> object.size(ok)
4019336 bytes
```

Let's create `ok2`, an exactly similar object but not within a function :

```
ok2 = vector('list',2)
ok2[[1]] = lm(a0~b1+b2+b3,data = data)
ok2[[2]] = lm(a0~b1+b2+b3,data = data)
```

... and check his size :

```
> object.size(ok2)
4019336 bytes
```

Here we are, `ok` and `ok2` are exactly the same, and so tells us R.
Problem, if we save these objects on hard drive as R object (with `save()` or `saveRDS()`) :

```
save(ok,file='ok.RData')
save(ok2,file='ok2.RData')
```

Theirs sizes on hard drive are respectively : `3 366 005  bytes` and `1 678 851  bytes`.
`ok` is 2 times bigger than `ok2` while they are exactly similar!

Even more strange, if you save a 'sublist' of our objects, lets say `ok[[1]]` and `ok2[[1]]` (objects once again totaly identical) :

```
a = ok[[1]]
a2 = ok2[[1]]
save(a,file='console/a.RData')
save(a2,file='console/a2.RData')
```

Theirs sizes on hard drive respectively : `2 523 284  bytes` and `838 977  bytes`.

Two things :
Why does the size of `a` differ from the size of `a2` on hard drive? Why does the size of `ok` differ from the size of `ok2` on hard drive?
And why `a` which is exactly half of `ok` sizes `2 523 284  bytes` while `ok` sizes at  `3 366 005  bytes` on HD?.

Am I missing something?

ps : I runned this test under Windows 7 32bits with R 2.15.1, 2.15.2, 2.15.3, 3.0.0, and with debian and R 2.15.1, R 2.15.2. I am having this problem every time.

**EDIT**

thx to @user1609452, here is a little trick which seems to be working :

```
test2 = function(k){

    tt = vector('list',k)
    for(i in 1:k){
        tt[[i]] = lm(a0~b1+b2+b3,data = data)
        attr(tt[[i]]$terms,".Environment") = .GlobalEnv
        attr(attr(tt[[i]]$model,"terms"),".Environment") = .GlobalEnv
    }
    tt
}
```

Formula objects come with their own environment and a lot of stuff in it. Put it to `NULL` or to .GlobalEnv and it seems to be working. Functions like predict.lm() still work and our saved objects have the right size on the HD. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at

```
> attr(ok[[1]]$terms,".Environment")
<environment: 0x9bcf3f8>
> attr(ok2[[1]]$terms,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

also

```
> ls(envir = attr(ok[[1]]$terms,".Environment"))
[1] "i"  "k"  "tt"
```

so `ok` is dragging around the environment of the function with it.

Also read `?object.size`

```
 The calculation is of the size of the object, and excludes the
 space needed to store its name in the symbol table.

 Associated space (e.g. the environment of a function and what the
 pointer in a ‘EXTPTRSXP’ points to) is not included in the
 calculation.
```

For example define a `test2` and an `ok3`

```
test2 = function(k){
    tt = vector('list',k)
    for(i in 1:k) tt[[i]] = lm(a0~b1+b2+b3,data = data)
    rr = tt
    tt
}

ok3 <- test2(2)
save(ok3, 'ok3.RdData')

> file.info('ok3.RData')$size
[1] 5043933
> file.info('ok.RData')$size
[1] 3366005
> file.info('ok2.RData')$size
[1] 1678851

> ls(envir = attr(ok3[[1]]$terms,".Environment"))
[1] "i"  "k"  "rr" "tt"
```

so `ok` is roughly twice as big as `ok2` because it has the extra `tt` and `ok3` is three times as big as it has `tt` and `rr`

```
> c(object.size(ok),object.size(ok2),object.size(ok3))
[1] 4019336 4019336 4019336
```

There is related discussion [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/03/24034.html)

Comment: Thx for pointing out the real problem @user1609452. I have updated my post with a solution which seems to be working. I am still confused by the way that's work though.